# Why Yii Criteria does not work directly?

Tags: php, yii, criteria

The following `Criteria` works fine:

```php
$criteria = new CDbCriteria(array(
    'condition' => 'Id_menu = 1 ',
    'select' => 'name',
    'limit' => 5,
));

$dp1 = new CActiveDataProvider('post', array(
   'criteria' => $criteria
));
```

However specifying `Criteria` directly on a model does not - it has no effect:

```php
$criteria = new CDbCriteria(array(
    'condition' => 'Id_menu = 1 ',
    'select' => 'name',
    'limit' => 5,
));

$dp1 = new CActiveDataProvider(Mdlfood::model()->find($criteria),array(),));
```

The following also does not work:

```php
$criteria = new CDbCriteria(array(
    'condition' => 'Id_menu = 1 ',
    'select' => 'name',
    'limit' => 5,
));

$model1 = new Mdlfood;
$model1->findAll($criteria);
$dp1 = new CActiveDataProvider($model1,array(),));
```

Can anyone explain why I cannot declare this configuration directly?

#### Added mdlfood

```php
class Mdlfood extends CActiveRecord{
public function tableName()
{
    return 'tblfood';
}


public function rules()
{

    return array(
        array('name, Url_picture, Price, Aboute, Id_foodType, Id_menu', 'required'),
        array('name', 'length', 'max'=>100),
        array('Url_picture, Aboute', 'length', 'max'=>2048),
        array('Price, Id_foodType, Id_menu', 'length', 'max'=>20),

        array('Id, name, Url_picture, Price, Aboute, Id_foodType, Id_menu', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}


public function relations()
{

    return array(
        'idMenu' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Tblrestmenu', 'Id_menu'),
        'idFoodType' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Tblfoodtype', 'Id_foodType'),
    );
}


public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'Id' => 'ID',
        'name' => 'Name',
        'Url_picture' => 'Url Picture',
        'Price' => 'Price',
        'Aboute' => 'Aboute',
        'Id_foodType' => 'Id Food Type',
        'Id_menu' => 'Id Menu',
    );
}

public function search()
{
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('Id',$this->Id,true);
    $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
    $criteria->compare('Url_picture',$this->Url_picture,true);
    $criteria->compare('Price',$this->Price,true);
    $criteria->compare('Aboute',$this->Aboute,true);
    $criteria->compare('Id_foodType',$this->Id_foodType,true);
    $criteria->compare('Id_menu',$this->Id_menu,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}

public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}
}
```

But, I think this is not related to Model, because this Criteria work  properly in the ActiveDataProvider.

Comment: what error is coming ?

Comment: none error, but criteria haven't effect

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this,

extra closing brackets, find()-> not in proper format

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria(array(
        'condition'=>'Id_menu = 1 ',
        'select'=>'name',
        'limit'=>5,
    ));


$dp1 = new CActiveDataProvider(Mdlfood::model()->find($criteria),array()); // extra closing brackets
```

Second way,

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria(array(
        'condition'=>'Id_menu = 1 ',
        'select'=>'name',
        'limit'=>5,
    ));
    $model1 = new Mdlfood;
    $model1->findAll($criteria);
    $dp1 = new CActiveDataProvider($model1,array());
```

Comment: tanx for answer Manadh, This is mistyped, but only on here

Comment: Can you paste model class Mdlfood() ?